# Find all K-length words accepted by finite automata (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, finite-automata

To represent **M** [finite automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) in prolog I'm using the following predicates:

```
states      /*states(Q) <=> Q is the list of automata's states*/
symbols     /*symbols(Sigma) <=> Sigma is the list of automata's input symbols*/
transition  /*transition(X, A, Y) <=> δ(X, A)=Y*/
startState  /*startState(S) <=> S is the start state of automata*/
finalStates /*finalStates(F) <=> F is the list of automata's final states */
```

For this sample automata:

[image]

the representation is:

```
states([q0, q1, q2]).
symbols([a, b]).
transition(q0, a, q1).
transition(q0, b, q2).
transition(q1, a, q2).
transition(q1, b, q0).
transition(q2, a, q1).
transition(q2, b, q2).
startState(q0).
finalStates([q2]).
```

Lets say that the fiven **w** word is recognized (accepted) by **M** automata <=> `accepted(W)` (W is a word's representing list)

```
accepted(W):-startState(Q0), accepted1(Q0, W)
```

Where `accepted1` <=> **w** belongs to a language which recognizes by automata's **Q** state.

```
accepted1(Q, []):- finalStates(F), !, member(Q, F).
accepted1(Q, [A|W]):- transition(Q, A, Q1), accepted1(Q1, W),!.
```

The question here is: how to find all positive **K**-length words accepted by given **M** finite automata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to setup a dummy list of the length you desire. You would add the auxiliary list as an argument to your `accepted1`:

```
accepted1(Q, [], []) :- finalStates(F), !, member(Q, F).
accepted1(Q, [_|K], [A|W]) :- transition(Q, A, Q1), accepted1(Q1, K, W),!.

accept_length(Q, R, Length) :-
    length(K, Length),
    accepted1(Q, K, R).
```

Answer (score 1):

From a declarative pov, You could just write a predicate `l_power_n(W,K)` which unifies W with any string in Σ^K. And then just generate and test with the goal `l_power_k(W,K), accepted(W).`

```
states([q0, q1, q2]).
symbols([a, b]).
transition(q0, a, q1).
transition(q0, b, q2).
transition(q1, a, q2).
transition(q1, b, q0).
transition(q2, a, q2). % Edited to reflect image
transition(q2, b, q1). % Edited to reflect image
startState(q0).
finalStates([q2]).

accepted(W):-startState(Q0), accepted1(Q0, W).

accepted1(Q, []):- finalStates(F), !, member(Q, F).
accepted1(Q, [A|W]):- transition(Q, A, Q1), accepted1(Q1, W),!.


% in_language(Word, Length): True if Word is of length Length and is part of the language.
l_power_k([], 0):- !.
l_power_k([WHead|WTail],K):-
    symbols(Symbols), member( WHead,Symbols ),
    K1 is K-1,
    l_power_k( WTail, K1).
```